# Disjoint union types in MLTT

Tags: logic, type-theory, intuitionistic-logic

In MLTT, by identifying propositions as types (and vice versa), a proposition carries the information regarding how a proof of the proposition is constructed. My question is related to this. Let $P:\textsf{U}$, then by definition, $(*)$ and $(**)$ are both well-formed types:
$$P+\neg P\quad(*)\quad\quad\quad\Pi X:\{P,\neg P\}.X+\neg X\quad (**)$$
In traditional logic, $(*)$ is equivalent to LEM; whilst $(**)$ expresses that for every $X$ that belongs to the set $\{P,\neg P\}$, LEM holds for $X$. In traditional logic, $(*)$ and $(**)$ are trivially equivalent to each other. My question is, given the proof-relevant property of propositions in MLTT, are $(*)$ and $(**)$ still mutually derivable? Thanks!

Comment: Your second formula seems to be a complicated way of writing $(P + \lnot P) \times (\lnot P + \lnot \lnot P)$. It is clear that $P + \lnot P$ can be derived from this. The converse amounts to deriving $\lnot P + \lnot \lnot P$ from $P + \lnot P$, which boils down to deriving $\lnot \lnot P$ from $P$.